# Gem install ruby-opengl on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: ruby, opengl

When I try to install the gem **ruby-opengl** on Mac OSX Lion it doesn't work.
I obtain a huge error message which the end is :

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [clang -fno-common  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-...]

Tasks: TOP => default => gl.bundle => gl-1.0-1.1.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [rake...]

Tasks: TOP => default => gl => ext/gl/gl.bundle
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Anybody have an idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just find out that there is an edited version of the original gem. I tried it out on my macosx lion installation and it works smoothly to me just running the following command:

```
gem install ruby-opengl2
```

You can find the fork at the url: https://github.com/pbosetti/ruby-opengl
I just think that the original gem is not mantained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue and a patch has been submitted. See: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29477&group_id=2103&atid=8185